# Alarm in android

Tags: android

I am using the following code for alarm, it will alert after 10 secs. Its works fine in emulator but in real device its forcely closing..can you guide me in correct way..
this is my actvity..

```
      public class Alarm1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,001000,intent,0);


AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}
}`
This is receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{

        Intent back = new Intent(context,Alarm.class);
        back.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        back.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        back.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        back.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        context.startActivity(back);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

}
```

}

This is to play Ringtone for alarm.

```
public class Alarm extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp; /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.up);
    mp.start();

    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    start.setOnClickListener(vvvvv);
}

private OnClickListener vvvvv = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mp.stop();
        finish();
    }
};
```

}

This is working fine in emulator but not on real device..i used permissions also..
I am using Samsung Galaxy 1.6.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: There are no errors in logcat

Comment: there has to be, make sure your device is selected...try to recreate the Exception, you should see the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)+10 );
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it helped me when I had the same problem

1. Connect your device, Un-install your app (if installed previously).
2. Run your application and wait till it gets installed on your phone.
3. Open Log cat, and now try running your application which according to you force closes, the log cat now shows multiple red and orange lines indicating your errors such has thread handling or low memory etc.

Which would look like this,

[image: This is my error log or log cat]

Please comment here with your error log, if you require further help.